# vb.Net ASP ModalPopupExtender not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've used the ModalPopupExtender from the AJAX Control Toolbox in Visual Studio 2012. I dropped the control onto my Delete Button and it added the following code to my .aspx file however when I test this it just runs the delete code as it did before without the confirmation dialog.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelCand" runat="server" Text="Delete Candidate" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btnDelCand_ConfirmButtonExtender" runat="server" ConfirmText="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnDelCand">
            </ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnDelCand_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnDelCand">
            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

I'm sure I've missed something, but I'm very new to using AJAX (First Attempt!!!), so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dialog according to your wish. 
Place it inside a panel.

Edit this code and replace your panel code with this panel code.

```
<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Button" />
<cc1:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
    cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" okcontrolid="btnOkay" 
    targetcontrolid="Button1" popupcontrolid="Panel1" 
    popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="true" 
    backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">
</cc1:modalpopupextender>
<asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: none" runat="server">
    <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
        <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader">Header</div>
        <div class="PopupBody">
            <p>This is a simple modal dialog</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Controls">
            <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Done" />
            <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is to replace

```
<asp:ScriptManager>
```

with

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```